# Download and show picture in a loop

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a list of links to pictures. Now I want to loop through the list and for each link dowload picture and show in Image right after that. My code

```
private void bDownload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string typedUrls = tbLinks.Text;
        string source = getPageSource(typedUrls);
        List<String> links = ExtractLinks(source);
        string threadID = getThreadID(typedUrls);


        for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
        {
            string path = downloadPic(links.ElementAt(i), threadID);
            showPicture(path);
        }
    }

private void showPicture(string path)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(path);
        iLatest.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
    }
```

When I run it it downloads pictures but only last picture is displayed. How to manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is running synchronously:

```
   //A synchronous (not asynchronous) loop!
   for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
    {
        string path = downloadPic(links.ElementAt(i), threadID);
        showPicture(path);
    }
```

Which means that the UI gets *no chance* to display the images as they are downloaded. It *does* update  when control is returned at the very end, displaying the last picture.

If you want to display each image as you are downloaded, you need to move the download to another thread or an `async` method.

If you want to loop through each image *after* they are downloaded, you'll just need a timer and code that loops through the image collection.

Comment: But can you tell how to do this? I've changed downloadPic to async and call to string path = await downloadPic(links.ElementAt(i), threadID) but it can't be that simple because it's still not working.

Comment: @korek That should have helped at least... How long are the downloads taking? Are they going so fast that even though its async it only shows the last one? Throwing an `await Task.Delay(2000)` would help confirm/deny that

Comment: After adding delay it's displaying picture right after. But if picture is small its download (or display) is faster and Task.Delay makes it longer. Is there a way to "fix" that?

Comment: @korek Sure, you just don't want to make your "loop" dependent on downloading. Download everything and loop through it with a timer.